# Saving the current Status of my ProgressBar

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save the Value in my ProgressBar so if I close the App (terminate it) and run it again, the same value is shown again. I tried this by using sharedpreferences but it's still not saving and I don't know how to solve it. I looked up everything I could find in the Internet but it's always kept very simplistic like "how to save a entertext into txt/xml" but that's not what I'm looking for.

```
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    fuelBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.fuelProgressBar);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    incFuel = sharedPref.getInt(FUELBAR, fuelBar.getProgress());
    fuelBar.setProgress(incFuel);
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt(FUELBAR, fuelBar.getProgress());
    editor.commit();
}

public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    fuelBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.fuelProgressBar);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    incFuel = sharedPref.getInt(FUELBAR, fuelBar.getProgress());
    fuelBar.setProgress(incFuel);
}
```

In my onCreate I also have those Variables declared

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
```

And in my MainActivity

```
int incFuel = 0;
final String FUELBAR = "fuelBar";

SharedPreferences sharedPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

I really have not a single clue what I'm missing and would highly appreciate some help.

Comment: i can only see put calls on your SharedPreference-Objects. Are you ever calling "get"?

Comment: I edited the code, please take a look at it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few issues.

1. Firstly, your `onStop()` is not needed, as the `onPause` and `onResume` are sufficient.
2. Your `onPause` and `onResume` are in reverse. (onResume is called after activity loads, onPause occurs when the activity is closed)
3. You also need to set the progress with the loaded value.

Below code should point you in the right direction.

```
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt(FUELBAR, fuelBar.getProgress());
    editor.commit();

}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume(); 
    fuelBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.fuelProgressBar);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    incFuel = sharedPref.getInt(FUELBAR, 0);
    fuelBar.setProgress(incFuel);
}

public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: gr8 thx for the Explanation it really helped and the program is working perfect now.